# Picking out respective serviceID for MAX() SQL SERVER- Row_number()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I needed guidance with a question I am working on and I have no previous experience solving it.

Basically, this is what the data looks like:

```
Customer Nr Service ID  Months left till  service expiry
57833357    149080495                   0
57624280    141110847                   0
57885974    149080449                   0
57885974    149080480                   7
57885974    149080499                   1
```

Scenario:

I am trying to figure out the `MAX()`  of "`Months left till  service expiry`" column, for each `Customer Nr`.

Requirement:

What I am basically looking for is, when picking the MAX() for each customer Nr, also pick out the respective `service ID` for the column that returns `MAX(Months left till  service expiry)`.

For instance, in the data above,`customer nr` =57885974 appears three times on different service ID:s.  The `service ID`=149080480  has 7 months left till expiry and that is the MAX()  for customer nr :57885974 .

How can make so it is only taking the `Customer Nr`, service ID( for the MAX()  months left till service expiry) and months left till service expiry?

Example below:

```
Customer Nr Service ID  Months left till  service expiry
57833357    149080495           0
57624280    141110847           0
57885974    149080480           7
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

Customer_nr,
[Months left till service expiry]=CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,EndDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '1'
 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,EndDate) BETWEEN  31 AND 60 THEN '2'
ELSE SOMETHING END

FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY Customer_nr,
serviceID,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,EndDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '1'
 WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,Date,EndDate) BETWEEN  31 AND 60 THEN '2'
ELSE SOMETHING END
```

In the next table I simply do a group by  with `Customer_nr` and MAX( [Months left till service expiry]) and it works. However, I would also need the respective `serviceID`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Prepare the data first in a CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Customer_nr order by [Months left till service expiry] desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As similar solution can be build by using [Sql CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)
Using SQL Server Ranking functions with Partition By is main solution for such filtering in Select queries

```
/*
create table tblExp (CustomerNr int, ServiceID  int, MonthsForExpiry int)
insert into tblExp select 57833357    ,149080495                   ,0
insert into tblExp select 57624280    ,141110847                   ,0
insert into tblExp select 57885974    ,149080449                   ,0
insert into tblExp select 57885974    ,149080480                   ,7
insert into tblExp select 57885974    ,149080499                   ,1
*/
;with cte as (
    select *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by CustomerNr Order By MonthsForExpiry desc)
    from tblExp
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```